# Display a changing string in console

Tags: c#

I'm trying out some new things in c#, and was wondering if I was able to replace a character over and over. Like it's the letter "A" for half a second, then "B", then "C" in a loop for a few seconds. Any suggestions?

EDIT:

This is an [example of what I want to do, but with text in a command line (MAJOR SEIZURE WARNING](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Dzcl2Whiog)

Comment: Clearly, it is pointless to change a string in memory over and over.  Are you asking how to DISPLAY a changing string like this?  On the console, or in a GUI?

Comment: Yes! Trying to display a changing string in a console

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string first = "ABC";
        for( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ )
        {
            Console.Write( first[i%3] + "\r" );
            Thread.Sleep( 500 );
        }
        Console.WriteLine( "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is super awesome, and works great, just wondering if you could explain some of it to me? Wondering what [i%3] is, and also what the \r and \n means? thanks!

Comment: Also, would I be able to do this with emojis/unicode characters?

Comment: These are very basic questions.  Are you doing a tutorial?  `%` is the modulus operator -- the remainder after division.  As `i` increases, `i%3` will go 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, etc.  The `"\n"` escape is a newline, which moves the cursor to the start of the next line.  Now that I look at it, it's not necessary because `WriteLine` adds one of those anyway.  `"\r"` is carriage return -- it moves the cursor to column one without starting a new line.

Comment: On Windows, whether this works with Unicode and emojis depends on the code page you have set and the font you're using in your terminal.  Most console fonts don't include a full Unicode set.

Comment: How do I change the console font? I'm just hitting f5 and running in the VS terminal, should I change that?